# Recursion relations and stability analysis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stability, complex-systems

I have a recursion relation in the form of the following two equations:

$X_{t+1} = X_t + V_{t+1} \\
V_{t+1} = wV_t + cy(g-X_t)$

I want to write these two equations into a matrix form so that I can analyze using some Linear algebra techniques. the problem is, I cannot seem to write as a square matrix.

---

Here is my partial solution:

$X_{t+1} = X_t + wV_t + cy(g-X_t)\\
V_{t+1} = wV_t + cy(g-X_t)$

I will group all $X_t$ and $V_t$ together:

$X_{t+1} = (1-cy)X_t + wV_t + cyg \\
V_{t+1} = -cyX_t + wV_t + cyg$

If I set $g=0$, then this would come into a nice clean form as follows:

$X_{t+1} = (1-cy)X_t + wV_t \\
X_{t+1} = -cyX_t + wV_t$

So this can be written as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix} X_{t+1} \\ V_{t+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1-cy & w \\ -cy & w\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X_t \\ V_t\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix therefore would be easy to diagonalize, etc. But we made a simplying case when $g=0$. Can I still make this form for the case when $g \neq 0$? How can I change the matrix?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically asking how to recast the nonhomogeneous matrix equation
$$\begin{pmatrix} X_{t+1} \\ V_{t+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1-cy & w \\ -cy & w\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X_t \\ V_t\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}cyg \\ cyg\end{pmatrix} $$
into a homogeneous one.

To save writing, let us call your matrix *M*, the left hand side vector $\vec{Y_{t+1}}$, and the constant vector on the right hand side $\vec{C}$, so your equation now presents like
$$
\vec{Y_{t+1}} =M \vec{Y_{t}} + \vec{C}~.
$$

Now define the telescopic variable
$$
\vec{Z_t}\equiv \vec{Y_{t+1}} -\vec{Y_{t}}= (M-I)\vec{Y_{t}}+\vec{C} ~,
$$
so that 
$$\vec{Z_{t+1}}= \vec{Y_{t+2}} -\vec{Y_{t+1}}\\ =M \vec{Y_{t+1}} + \vec{C}      - M \vec{Y_{t}} -\vec{C} = M \vec{Z_{t}} ~,
$$
a homogeneous recursion, all right.

You may now proceed to study the eigenvalues of *M*, and so on and so forth.... to determine the orbit of your vector.

See [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).